# Servers compare, to run BIG MySql DB

Tags: mysql, database, hard-drive, dedicated-server

I have an question about this 2 dedicated servers,... 
WATH is BETTER to run an website with an large MySql Data Base (4 - 6 GB)

------My actual server-------

- Intel  Xeon E5-1650v2 - 6c/12t - 3,5 / 3,8 GHz

  Ram: 128 GB

  Memory: DDR3 ECC 2133 MHz

  Disks: 3x600GB SAS  HARD + Cache 80Go SSD

------I want to change to this server----------

- Intel  Xeon 2x E5-2630v3 - 16c/32t - 2,4 / 3,2 GHz

  Ram: 128 GB

  Memory: DDR4 ECC 1866 MHz

  Disks: 2x480GB SSD SOFT

---

Of corse, the second server, have beeter procesor, better memory... but the disks?

About my website:
Is an very light web, dont use images, videos,... I dont have big files, and is developed with laravel and run in cPanel (centOS)

The problem is the DB, becouse all content (for example, images) are requested from external websites, and all this routes are stored in the DB. So, for now, my DB have 4GB, but in the next monts, can have 6GB.

I need an very fast server for the DB.

MANY THANKS.

Comment: Get some data and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database should rock on either of those specs. Your entire database can fit in RAM and that will definitely make your web app/DB very responsive. Your database is really not large. 6 GB these days for a DB is small-to-medium size.

I'd go the SSD right. If you can, go with RAID-1 for data protection.